# How to do two rows inside of a Hero-Unit without responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a web on Bootstrap and I'm getting into some serious troubles that I can't solve even with Bootstrap documentations. So, this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <h2>Two Rows</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span6">
            <center>
            <img src="../img/renders/example.png" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height= 200px; margin-top: 80px">
            <img src="../img/covers/some_image.jpg" title="Image title" class="img-rounded propiedades_imagenes">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="span6">
            <div class="well" style="margin-top:130px">
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#link">
                <i class="icon-download"></i> Download</a>

              <a class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" href="#random.html" style="margin-left:272px">
                <i class="icon-random icon-white"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to create two rows inside of a Hero-Unit, the thing is it worked when I had the responsive design activated but when I activate it the page just do some crazy stuff with the design in smaller and bigger screens than mine, so I just deleted the link to bootstrap-responsive.css and I put a "class=row" instead of "class=row-fluid", but now it just creates one row instead of two and put all the content of the second row under the first one.

Am I doing something wrong? I know how to do this with responsive, but it messes up all my work.

Image of what I want and what I get with the responsive design: http://i1129.photobucket.com/albums/m518/ZoxSoft/Capturadepantalla2013-08-13alas000037_zps064f71b1.png

Comment: do you have a link to show us Visual people what is going on?

Comment: post your solution as an answer and accept it as an answer so that others looking will see that you solved your problem, and can easily find the solution you came to

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Bootstrap or Hero-unit

but I think that you need another Div with `class="row"`

it is hard to troubleshoot with out a visual of what is going on and what it is supposed to be doing. but first glance to me says you need another div tag with the class of row.

you have 3 `</div>` at the end of the code snippet that you gave and only 2 that need to be closed?

**NEW**

in your first image link it looks like you have a lot of styling but no **Title Attribute** and no **Class Attribute**

with out that class attribute your responsive and Hero-Unit won't know to grab it

Comment: I tried adding another "class=row" but it didn't work. I added an image on the first post so you can see what I want.

Oh, and the <div> error was my fault when I edited the code!

Comment: I tried adding a "img-rounded" class to the first one but still nothing. Just one row and the other one (the one with "Descargar" buttons and the random one) goes to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out. I created two new classes for each div, one for the left one and another for the right one, I put this code into de first one:

```
width: 50%;
float:left;
```

And for the right one:

```
width: 50%;
float:right;
```

After that, did a few changes in the margin of the objects to fit in the page and finally got it!